# Drag the selected content from browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to know is there any way to find out that, to know what has been selected in browser using jquery if we select the content in browser(like highlight when you click and drag).

For example, I have a table and I selected(like highlight when you click and drag) a row of that table and now I want to drag it to an input. When I am dragging the content,do I know any possiblity of what I am dragging the content from browser. Here I am not using any jquery drag and drop of the table. Is it possible with drag and drop,If possible can i have an example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would drag the contents of a table row to a text input.

Include jQuery and jQueryUI:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Make a table and input element:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Dog</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fish</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cat</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Choose an animal" id="dropzone" />
</p>
```

Add the following JS:

```
$("tr").draggable({
  appendTo: "body", 
  helper: "clone"
});

$("#dropzone").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $(this).val(ui.draggable.text().trim());
  }
});
```

Inside the drop function `$(this)` refers to the element on to which the first element has been dragged, so it is a simple matter of setting its value to the text of the element which was dropped.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/jfntoqvd/)